# Conversion from Roman numerals in Dive into Python seems to output an extra character

Tags: python, arrays, roman-numerals

I am learning Python 2.7 by *Dive to Python*. Here are the codes of "Converting between Roman Numerals and Arabic numerals":

```
romanNumeralMap = (('M',1000),
        ('CM',900),
        ('D',500),
        ('CD',400),
        ('C',100),
        ('XC',90),
        ('L',50),
        ('XL',40),
        ('X',10),
        ('IX',9),
        ('V',5),
        ('IV',4),
        ('I',1))
def toRoman(n):
    result = ""
    for numeral, integer in romanNumeralMap:
        while n >= integer:
            result += numeral
            n -= integer
    return result

def fromRoman(s):
    result = 0
    index = 0
    for numeral, integer in romanNumeralMap:
        while s[index:index+len(numeral)] == numeral:
            result += integer
            index += len(numeral)
    return result

print toRoman(1356)
print fromRoman('MCMLXXII')
```

But I am puzzled by the  procedure of this part:

```
for numeral, integer in romanNumeralMap:
        while s[index:index+len(numeral)] == numeral:
            result += integer
            index += len(numeral)
```

When executed in the **second** time, the `s[index:index+len(numeral)]` returns `CM`, but I think it should return `C`, because the `index = 1` after the first execution, then `index+len(numeral) = 2`, and `s[1: 2] = 'C'`. What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second iteration of the `for` loop, `index` is indeed `1`
`numeral` is `CM` and `integer` is `900`

`len(numeral)` == `2`, and

`s[1:1+2]` == `S[1:3]` == `'CM'`

Answer (score 0):

`numeral` is equal to `CM` and `len(cm) == 2`. `s[1: 1 + 2] == s[1:3] == 'CM'`

Since the numeral is actually two characters, you read two characters of the input to match against.

Comment: If I write the (CM, 900) behind (C, 100), then the result will be C ? More to question, Is the while procedure obey a certain order of the elements it checks?

Comment: Are you aware that CM is something different than MC in Roman numbers? Now, concerning the while procedure, the order it checks the map is in the order it is given, due to the surrounding `for` loop.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I know the difference between them. And do you mean the order of elements within the map given to while procedure determines the while check order?

Comment: I think you should step through this program and inspect what variables contain at certain stages, that would clear up your questions immediately.